# How to parse ini file with duplicate sections in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, ini

I've got an ini file which looks like:

```
[account]
user= saas
pwd=di1Z-ARMfKF2
description= as
expdate= 2015-08-22
caid = 1702,1830,0B00,0D95,0500,0648,0B02,09C7,1722,1834,098C
betatunnel= 1834.FFFF:1722,1833.FFFF:1702
group= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30
cccmaxhops= 5
cccreshare= 0

[account]
user= sdadsa
pwd= XnbawAH/ZYRP
description= sdasda
expdate= 2016-08-13
caid= 1702,1830,0B00,0D95,0500,0648,0B02,09C7,1722,1834,098C
betatunnel= 1834.FFFF:1722,1833.FFFF:1702
group= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30
cccmaxhops= 5
cccreshare= 0
```

I need to find for example the content of "user" where description is "sdasda".
I tried:

```
<?php
$accounts = [];
$accountIniArr = explode('[account]',   file_get_contents('oscam.user')); 
foreach ($accountIniArr as $accIni) 
{ 
$account = parse_ini_string($accIni); 
$accounts[$acc['user']] = $account; 
}
echo $accounts['sdadsa']['description'];
?>
```

Doesn't work, seems like the array doesn't get parsed correctly, any idea how to fix?

Comment: What does `$ini_array` look like? I'm pretty sure you cannot use `parse_ini_file()` like this; duplicate section headings would get overwritten. You should use a database instead.

Comment: Hmm seems like you're right. Any idea how to get the file parsed like I described above?

Comment: You'd have to parse it manually. Use a database :-)

Comment: No way, I need to parse from the file above. The software doesn't support database for storing the user data.

Comment: Explode on `[account]` then explode on `\n`.

Comment: @chris85 - Explode on `[account]`, and then you can use [parse_ini_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) for the individual elements of the exploded array.... so even easier

Comment: Sounds like a pretty hairy task, isn't it?

Comment: I have two suggestions for you. One: do not store the password as plaintext unless it's absolutely necessary. Two: you might want to consider making an `Account` class to store the data read from the ini files.

Answer (score 3):

Leading on from the discussion in the comments, you cannot use ini sections with identical names, so to use that ini format, you would have to do a little custom parsing. Here's an example of what chris85 and Mark baker were meaning:

```
$accounts = [];

// Read the .ini file contents, and explode it by the section identifier
$accountIniArr = explode('[account]', file_get_contents('users.user'));

// Iterate through the resultant array, and parse each of the user account 
// .ini settings, storing them in a multi-dimensional array as you go
for ($i=1; $i<count($accountIniArr); $i++)
{
    $accountIni = $accountIniArr[$i];
    $account = parse_ini_string($accountIni);
    $accounts[$account['user']] = $account;
}
```

This would produce a multidimensional array containing all of the accounts, with the first index being the `user` field. To use the sample data you posted, the array would be:

```
[
 saas => [
  user => saas,
  pwd => di1Z-ARMfKF2,
  description => as,
  expdate => 2015-08-22,
  caid => 1702,1830,0B00,0D95,0500,0648,0B02,09C7,1722,1834,098C,
  betatunnel => 1834.FFFF:1722,1833.FFFF:1702,
  group => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30,
  cccmaxhops => 5,
  cccreshare => 0
 ],
 sdadsa => [
  user => sdadsa,
  pwd => XnbawAH/ZYRP,
  description => sdasda,
  expdate => 2016-08-13,
  caid => 1702,1830,0B00,0D95,0500,0648,0B02,09C7,1722,1834,098C,
  betatunnel => 1834.FFFF:1722,1833.FFFF:1702,
  group => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30,
  cccmaxhops => 5,
  cccreshare => 0
 ]
]
```

However, you could also just put the username into the ini file section headings instead of `account`.

Comment: How to get for example the field "description" of user "sdadsa"? I tried this echo $accounts['sdadsa'['description']];

Comment: @dehniz As you would with any other multi-dimensional array, i.e. `$accounts['sdadsa']['description']`

Comment: I edited code above, did I need to use "array_search" to find the value of the description field, where user=sdasda? The username would be "sdadsa", hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @dehniz See the updated code snippet in my answer; the for loop should actually start at array position 1 rather than 0 (the first element in the array is empty) and there was a typo. I did a quick unit test and all is now well.